# (Python 3) Program closes upon input

Tags: python-3.x

I created a Pig Latin translator. I run the program, it opens, I enter a word, and as soon as I hit 'enter' the program closes. Why is this?

```
userWord = input('Enter any word:')

pig = "ay"


if len(userWord) > 0 and userWord.isalpha():
    word = userWord.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new = word[1:] + first + pig
    print(new)
else:
    print("INPUT INVALID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not interpret what you typed in as a string. You will need to put "" to denote it is a string.

For example:

```
Enter any word: blah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    userWord = input('Enter any word: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

But if you put ""

```
Enter any word:"blah"
lahbay
```

Comment: It works fine in IDLE. The problem I'm having is, after I save the file and try to open it separately, it'll ask for input and whenever I press ENTER to send my input, the program immediately closes.